# Grails geo - location initializer

Tags: grails, geoip

We are developing our project in grails. And we want to show data to user according to the country from where they are accessing our website.
I have a field where I store the country location. By using geoip grails plugin.

My question is can we initialize the session with the country name from where the site is being excessed before it hits any controller/action, let say in some config file or somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do it in a [Filter](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.6%20Filters).  Something like this, placed in `grails-app/conf` as `GeoFilters.groovy`:

```
class GeoFilters {
  def geoIpService

  def filters = {
    countryCheck(controller:'*', action:'*') {
      before = {
        if( !session.geolocation ) {
          session.geolocation = geoIpService.getLocation( request.remoteAddr )
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Should (I haven't tried it though) check to see if `geolocation` exists in the session, and if it doesn't, it should fetch it from the `geoIpService`.

Comment: Hi tim, thanx for the quick reply :) I guess this filter will initialize the session with the ip of the server, where the war will be deployed. Will it re-initialize the session according to the user who is going to access our site

Comment: @lucky Phillipe is right, `request.remoteAddr` is the IP address of the client as a `String`...

Comment: Actually after using the above code I restarted my application on localhost. just after the message : Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/xyz this filter were executed. So i was confused

Comment: I thought this filters would get executed when someone new access our website

Comment: @lucky why don't you test it on main server first instead of testing it at local.

Comment: @lucky this filter should get executed every time anyone accesses a grails action.  Maybe describing the problem you having would be useful to those trying to help?

Comment: @tim it actually worked "this filter should get executed every time anyone accesses a grails action." and thanx for the solution. Every time a new user access the website a session is created according to his location. :)